# Connect to TFS server in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, tfs, ssms

I have a TFS project that can be found at `http://machinename:8080/tfs/tfs.project`

I can get to the web interface via `http://machinename:8080/tfs/web`.

I have SQL Server Management Studio 2008 installed with Visual Studio Team Foundation Server MSSCCI Provider and Team Explorer 2010.

However when I go to add a TFS server to the list I am presented with a very restrictive window that will only allow me to put in the server name and a port number. With that in place I am unable to connect to my TFS server can anybody offer some advice on how to get round this??

I keep getting a HTTP 404 error because it is looking at the root - `http://machinename:8080`

Comment: There was a hotfix required to make this work for Visual Studio 2008. I don't know if that fix corrects the problem for SSMS. Probably not, since I don't think it was an MSSCCI fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same problem with the same exact parameters. I discovered that if you enter the full URL in the server textbox it resolves. Example: `http://machinename:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection`

Nothing explains this clearly.

Comment: This is still used in TFS2008 with SQL Server 2012 and it still works as described in the solution.